# What's the difference between Apache 1.x and 2.x when it comes to Gzip compression

Tags: apache, compression, gzip, mod-deflate

Couple of tests I ran show that Apache 2.x has better compression(mod_deflate) compared to Apache 1.x. Let me know if there's a detailed benchmarking done by anyone.

Answer (score 0):

There are some comparisons in this [Linux Journal article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6802) with some compression numbers between apache 1.3's mod_gzip vs apache 2.0's mod_deflate.

Comment: Thanks @jon-lin. This looks good for now. If I don't find anything concrete, I'll run a test on my own and publish some results. Here's another article that mentions that Apache 2's mod_deflate is better than mod_zip (by 60%). Both articles are from 2004.
http://ilia.ws/archives/32-Apache-1-vs-Apache-2-Performance.html

Answer (score 0):

The noted differences in compression and speed are an inherent trade-off that is user-selectable on compression vs. time.